# npm install changes file permissions

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, npm-publish

I have a package (@takinola/handy) that contains the file

```
node_modules/@takinola/handy/public/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
```

On my development machine (Ubuntu 14.04.5), before running "npm publish", the file permissions are

```
-rwxrwxr--
```

However, after running "npm install", the installed file permissions change (even on the same machine) to

```
-rwx-rwx---
```

How come the npm publish -> npm install process changes the permissions on this file?  Why are other files not affected?